# What is the potential difference between A and B?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Here is  a schematic digram of the circuit.

[image]

And I take a equivalent circuit for  the  above circuit as shown below.

[image]

These are the things that I can figure about this circuit.

1. Potential difference across 200 ohm resistor is 10V
2. Potential difference across 100 ohm resistor is 10V.

So is it possible to take the answer as below,

For 100 ohm resistor ====> Potential difference is 10v

Since the equivalent resistance between P ans Q is 150 ohm

For 150 ohm resistor ====> Potential difference is (10/100).150 V

Therefore according to my way the potential difference between P and Q is  15V.

Is this method is correct.?

I am not sure.

Comment: The top path is incorrect. Examine the placement of the resistors.

Comment: I didn't get  what you have written

Comment: There should be a 50 Ohm resistor between P and +10V, your simplification is wrong.

Comment: I think it isn't

Comment: @Ontheway  Your call.  If you are sure that its correct, then turn in the homework.  See what professor says.

Comment: What I want to know is the accuracy of my answr

Comment: Your answer is nonsense.  You have calculated 15V for the difference between P and Q and it's greater than the voltage source.  Does that not strike you as odd?

Comment: Yeah ...something have gone wrong

Comment: Okay I got the point, now I don't need any help for this question

Comment: I think Ive made the same assumptions. Let fools communicate. The resistor will affect the voltage, but by current limiting when the draw of the load is affected. We can't apply thevenin to an incomplete circuit and say less current will provide more voltage. Just limiting current. Circuit plan looks like a diode bridge, where forward voltage of assemblage create halfwave pd, even negative charge and ac frequency for output. Resistivity will affect amps and equate to volts when dissipation is spread through more doped regions /plates. With a larger surface area of plates and electromagnetic wi

Answer (score 0):

By voltage division, the potential at P is 1/4 of 10 v, or 2.5 v.  Q is plainly at 10 v; so the difference between Q and P is 7 1/2 volts, which is 10 minus 2.5. And yes, your simplification IS dead wrong; plus, you are NOT going to have 15 volts from anywhere to anywhere in a circuit with only a 10volt source!

Comment: For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment.  We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when the O.P. had demonstrated sufficient effort of his own.  Otherwise, we would be doing the O.P. a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time.  See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).